# How to run PowerShell script without terminal window?

Tags: powershell

The shortcut below executes powershell.exe and passes it the script vscode.ps1.  It works except that for all my attempts, it still displays a terminal window briefly when running.  You can see I've passed parameters which is supposed to prevent this, but I still see the window.  What do I have to do to execute a PS script from a shortcut without the terminal window being displayed?

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file C:\Users\bernie\OneDrive\PowerShell\vscode.ps1 C:\Users\bernie\OneDrive\Documents\windows.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known issue, see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028#issuecomment-583834582

As @Ciantic mentioned, the best way to work around this issue is by using a VB script:

In, say `ps-run.vbs` put

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set args = Wscript.Arguments
For Each arg In args
    objShell.Run("powershell -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive ""&"" ""'" & arg & "'"""),0
Next
```

Then use it to run the command you want, e.g.

```
 wscript "C:\Path\To\ps-run.vbs" "C:\Other\Path\To\your-script.ps1"
```

I use something like this to run a task frequently without seeing any flashing windows.

Comment: Thanks.  As a workaround I just configured the shortcut which runs the powershell command to run the window minimized.  At least I don't see it unless I want to!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Powershell can't completely do this. But VBScript can do this. Also I use [Hidden Start](https://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html) which can start any program hidden or bypass UAC.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to run PowerShell scripts completely hidden (not even a flash) is to use this little [**RunHidden**](https://lesferch.github.io/RunHidden/) executable.